# How to deal with nose extensions that are not available under certain versions of python?

Tags: python, nosetests

I do have several python packages that I do test using nosetest, and as expected one of the steps is to run the tests using several versions of Python.

The main problem is that most nose extensions are not compatible with all versions of python and not having them install will prevent you from running the tests (nose will stop if it finds any unknown option inside `[nosetest]` from `setup.cfg`.

Example of extensions: `yanc`, `xtraceback`,`machineout`,'nose_exclude`

I do have to run the tests with `Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.2`

I do not need to run all of these for all versions of python, but still how should I reconfigure the execution of the tests in order not to loose them?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the nosetests as it's too hard to make them work on different versions of python and switch to `tox` eventually calling `py.test` from `tox`.